# How to Increase or decrease length of array

Tags: c#, arrays

//suppose

```
object[] myarray = new object[3];
myarray[0] = 10;
myarray[1] = 20;
myarray[2] = 30;
```

Can I change the length of my array according to requirements.
Like

```
myarray[0] = 10;
myarray[1] = 20;
myarray[2] = 30;
myarray[3] = 40;
```

Comment: No, arrays are only preallocated data structures. You may want to add a tag for your programming language, though

Answer (score 1):

You do not. Arrays have a static length (as is obvious by missing resize methods and the static constructor variable for the length).

You need to allocate a new array and copy the elements over.